# Showing that $\frac{21n+4}{14n+3}$ is irreducible for every natural number n.

Tags: solution-verification, induction, euclidean-algorithm

I wanted to prove that the fraction is irreducible using induction and have written the following proof:

Let's take $n=1$, then $\frac{21\cdot1+4}{14\cdot1+3}=\frac{24}{17}$ which is not divisible. assuming that for $n=k$ it is also not divisible. So now we will show that it is not divisible for $n=k+1$.
$$\frac{21(k+1)+4}{14\cdot(k+1)+3}=\frac{21k+21+4}{14k+14+3}=\frac{21k+25}{14k+17}$$ we have assumed that the fraction is not true for n=k and it is also not true for $n=k+1$.

Is this a concrete proof of induction?

P.s I know the Euclidean algorithm proof but wanted to try it with induction.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac {21k+25}{14k+17}$ is irreducible?  That doesn't look any easier than the original question.

Comment: I would have thought that this was more of a question regarding properties of the gcd.  For instance, it's easy to see that $\gcd(21n+4, 14n+3)=\gcd(7n+1,14n+3)$.  Keep going with that.

Comment: I need help in how do i proceed after this step, should i again use induction? but i think that will again lead to another irreducible fraction.

Comment: As I said, I do not imagine that this is a good candidate for induction.  I suggest proceeding along the lines I started.

Comment: If we show that gcd$(21k + 4, 14k+3)$ = gcd$(21(k+1)+4, 14(k+1) + 3 ) = 1$, we are done.

Comment: $-2(21n+4)+3(14n+3)=1$

Comment: @chin_chillin_maths FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B21n%2B4%7D%7B14n%2B3%7D%24&p=1), there are several AoPS threads that deal with this problem. In particular, there's [Trivial IMO problems compilation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1193098p5828547) which states the problem is the #$1$ question from the $1959$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint :** $$3 \times (14n+3)-2 \times (21n+4)=1$$

Now, Bezout is the man.

Comment: Yes i know the bezout and the euclidean algo, i want to ask wether we can prove this by induction and if yes which step am i missing in my proof.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).